# Play audio only once

Tags: android-studio, audio

I have an audio in the Main Activity and it is played every time I enter the Main Activity. I want it to play only once, regardless of whether you switch screens and come back! I want him to plays only the first time he enters the Main Activity and the other times he is null!

" '@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void getTimeFromAndroid() {

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12) {
        setBrightness(brilhoManha + 155);
        saudacao.setText("BOM DIA, SEJA BEM-VINDO");

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!flag) {
                    play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audiobomdia);
                    play.start();
                }
            }
        }, 2000);

    }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 18){
        setBrightness(brilhoManha + 155);
        saudacao.setText("BOA TARDE, SEJA BEM-VINDO");
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!flag) {
                    play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audioboatarde);
                    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.main);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }else if(timeOfDay >= 18 && timeOfDay < 24){
        saudacao.setText("BOA NOITE, SEJA BEM-VINDO");
        setBrightness(brilhoNoite + 60);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!flag) {
                    play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audioboanoite);
                    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.main);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }else if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 6){
        saudacao.setText("BOA NOITE, SEJA BEM-VINDO");
      setBrightness(brilhoNoite+60);
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (!flag) {
                    play = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.audioboanoite);
                    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.main);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
} '"
```

This is my code in Main Activity, it is used to play an audio and a greeting message appears according to the time.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

remove `public int status = 0` from MainActivity. then create class G and add `public static int status = 0` . that must be static :

```
public class G extends Application{
    
    public static int status = 0;
    public static SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // if you want to not play even 
        // after exit from app, add these too
      
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        status = preferences.getInt("STATUS", 0);

       }

 }
```

then add  `android:name="your package name.G"` to manifest in application block

like this :

```
<application
android:name="your package name.G"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

then add this where that audio playing in MainActivity :

```
if(G.status==0) {
    //write codes to play audio
    G.status = 1;
}
```

if you want to not play even after exit from app, add this method to onCreate MainActivity :

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
 if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

  preferences.edit().putInt("STATUS", G.status).apply();

 }

 return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: It still didn't work out, if you enter an activity and return to the Main Activity, it will play the audio again.